# Ngrx how to digest the entire action stream at the top of the stream

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have actions laden all over my app.  I have a root effect `EffectsModule.forRoot([AmplitudeEffects])`

which runs to the below function

```
@Injectable()
export class AmplitudeEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}

  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  public amp = this.actions$.pipe(
    tap(() =>
      console.log(this.actions$)
      AmplitudeService.sendValues(eventCategory, eventName, eventDescription, eventProperty)
    )
  );
}
```

but what I am seeing in the console is the `tap()` i have on each effect showing the correct data, but the `tap() => console.log(this.actions$)` is showing something else regarding the actions that I don't understand.  How can I get a clearer console view of what actioned happened in which sequence through the `EffectsModule.forRoot`... I would like to see the stuff coming out of `index.js` in my console.log in amplitude.effects.ts... Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're logging the actions observable, but you need the action

```
  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  public amp = this.actions$.pipe(
    tap((action) =>
      console.log(action)
      AmplitudeService.sendValues(eventCategory, eventName, eventDescription, eventProperty)
    )
  );
```